# C#: set active form, change field on that form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add an item to listBox1 that's on Form4 from Form5. I researched it and found an answer on this site that is supposed to work:

```
var form = Form.ActiveForm as Form4;
form.listBox1.Items.Add("aaa");
```

I get a "NullReferenceException". That's the solution I found but I don't even understand why it should work. My instance of Form4 is called formfour and I create like this from the main form:

```
Form4 formfour = new Form4();
formfour.Show();
```

The listBox1 modifiers is set to public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting the `NullRefereneException` is that your current `ActiceForm` is not being casted as `Form4`, that is why you get `null` in your instance `form`.

From the question it appears that you have `Form4` opened and you want to set that form as active:

You can use [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property and get an instance of `Form4` like:

```
Form4 form = Application.OpenForms["Form4"] as Form4;
if(form != null)
   form.Focus();
```

also if you want to add items to list box on existing form then:

```
form.listBox1.Items.Add("aaa");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Form5

```
   Form4 frm4= new Form4();
   frm4.listbox.Items.Add("aaa"); 
   // make sure that the listbox on form4 is set to public from its properties
```

To refresh the form4 use

```
   frm4.refresh();
```

And for more go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911190/c-sharp-reload-redraw-form-upon-settings-update-in-dialog-box#)

Comment: But that would create a new form4 no? What if I want to add it to the form that's already open?

Comment: Then use the instance you have already created to open the form, add the items to the list and refresh the form4.